# Can anyone recommend a voltage controlled voltage source circuit?

Tags: analog, design, voltage-controlled-resistor

Basically I want to have a source of 0 to 3 volts that will control the output of a different source from 0 to 100% (or close to it).

For example, if my source is 2v and I set my control to 1.5V (half the control range) the output will be 1V or with a 1V source it will be 0.5V out.  Vout = (Vc/VcMax) * Vsource.

I know this can be done through PWM or possibly VCR (can you recommended a good VCR circuit?), but I'm looking for something has a small footprint and cost. I am hoping for a transistor\jfet\mosfet type solution with less than 2 opamps.

If you know of anything it would be very helpful.

Comment: You didn't specify your circuit conditions.   i.e. how much load???    milliamps or amperes???   it matters ALOT.

Comment: It will be used as a reference voltage. so low current. 1-10mA would be plenty.

Comment: Please *edit your question* with the current requirement.  While you're at it, mention how rapidly it needs to respond, and how accurate it needs to be.  PWM may end up being your best friend for this.

Comment: Sounds like an analog multiplier

Comment: You could be right, how would something like that work? Can you link a circuit?

Answer (score 2):

This circuit's a good VCVS, it essentially puts whatever voltage is on the + terminal, doubles it and puts it on a load. This is only the basic circuit, you will need to compensate it with a capacitor (depending on what type of opamp you use and what it's bandwidth is). And you may need a current limiting resistor (like 100Ohm) between the op amp and the transistor.

Also if you eliminate the resistor attenuation, you get 1:1 on the V+ terminal and what the load sees.

The Vcc should be set to the largest voltage the load would need plus 0.7V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiscFC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this only works is VCC is a know constant. In my design the VCC would range from 1 to 3V. This has the same problem as just using an emitter follower.

Comment: Vcc is a regulated value, can you use a voltage regulator or power supply in your design?

Comment: The VCC is really a reference voltage and will very from 1-3Vdc. I want to be able to set percentage of VCC(Vref), whatever it might be, with a control voltage.

Comment: You can do that with this circuit (voltage in) is the set point

Comment: Ah, I understand the confusion now. I'd like my control voltage range to stay the same (0-3v) so if I'm using a DAC to control it I can take advantage of the full range. So if I set my control voltage to 1.5V(1.5/3 = 0.5) I always get 50% whatever VCC  is.

Comment: Yep, or you can change the divider to change the range

Comment: @ISEMI also, if you only wanted to use a DAC, you could choose a DAC with an external reference input. Then you wouldn't need any extra circuitry.

Comment: That is a good idea. But the DAC was just an example. The control voltage could be from anything a user selected.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to thank you for your help and say I stumbled on this solution in simulation and I'm going to try and test it out when I find sometime.

[image]